# use of multiple custom scripts in metadata parameter of the LaunchInstanceDetails method in oci.core.model

Tags: windows, python-2.7, chef-infra, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I understand that the `LaunchInstanceDetails` method in `oci.core.model` has a parameter -> `metadata` , wherein one of the metadata key-names that can be used to provide information to Cloud-Init is -> “`user_data`” , which can be used to run custom scripts by Could-Init when provided in a base64-encoded format.

In my Python code to create a Windows VM,while launching the instance, I have a requirement to run 2 custom scripts:

1. Script to login to Windows machine via RDP – this is absolute(needs to be executed every time a new Windows VM is created without fail) – Currently , we have included this in the metadata parameter while launching the instance, as below:

   instance_metadata['user_data'] = oci.util.file_content_as_launch_instance_user_data(path_init)
2. Bootstrap script to Install Chef during the initialization tasks  - this is conditional ( this needs to run only if the user wishes to Install Chef and we internally handle it by means of a flag in the code) – Yet to be implemented as we need to identify if more than one custom script (conditional in this case) can be included.

Can someone help me understand if and how we can achieve to include multiple scripts(keeping in mind the conditional clause) in a single metadata variable or can we have multiple metadata or some other parameter in this service that could be utilised to run the Chef Installation script

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest combining these into a single script and using the conditional in a `if` statement to install Chef as required.